# How to disable dnsmasq cache

Tags: dnsmasq

I just want to disable the caching functionality, I do not need it and it only creates bad behavior in my environment.

Not interested in any other solution, if you do not know, do not comment.

Comment: That's some attitude, coming from someone who didn't read the man page.

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual page](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html):

```
-c, --cache-size=<cachesize>
    Set the size of dnsmasq's cache. The default is 150 names. 
    Setting the cache size to zero disables caching. 
    Note: huge cache size impacts performance.
```

Comment: Bernd, you give a lot of good help, especially in comments where you don't get points for it. So I'm upvoting this answer, partly as a proxy for all of that. But this question didn't deserve an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. Yes, I hope OP learns how to RTFM (and to switch off an attitude that comes across as arrogance).